# Is there a ANSI Color Plugin for Bamboo Cucumber Reports?

Tags: continuous-integration, cucumber, bamboo, cd

Bamboo jobs for Cucumber regression tests gives pretty large log file.
Clicking on logs just gives a subset which is ANSI color formatted, however it is truncated to last 1000 lines.
There is an option to view the full log but it isnt ANSI formatted. Example as below

```
[0;32mI
```

With Jenkins I have used the "ANSI Color Plugin".
Is there a similar one for Bamboo and how to install it?

Appreciate hany help

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that is currently not built into Bamboo and there are no available plugins on the marketplace.

However, it is a feature others have requested and you can track the progress of it (and vote for it) [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-17390).